# How can I determine when exactly I updated Windows to the latest fall creator release?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

I'm troubleshooting an issue that may or may not be related to the latest Windows 10 Fall Creators Update.  I don't recall when exactly I upgraded.  Is there a log or cmdlet I can run that will tell me how long I've been on the current version of Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will press the Windows Flag key [image] one time and then start typing in "*Windows Update Settings*" until you see **Windows Update Settings** appears at which point you will click on that to open up the options.

[image]

From the **Windows Update** screen you will then select the **View installed update history** option.

[image]

From the **View installed update history** screen you will see the date the **Feature Updates** and the date those were installed.

[image]

Comment: @MikeB Additionally, you can run the PowerShell `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` and press Enter and it will create a log for you named `WindowsUpdate.log` that you can look thru to see if it gives you further detail. It created it right on my desktop when I ran it on Windows 10.